# Cannot reindex Catalog URL Rewrites

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, reindex

I get the following error when I try to reindex my Catalog URL Rewrites.

```
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog URL Rewrites index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-hand-power-tools' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_URL_KEY_STORE_ID_VALUE'' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(392): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('catalog_categor...', Array)
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(301): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->saveCategoryAttribute(Object(Varien_Object), 'url_key')
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(320): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshCategoryRewrites(Object(Varien_Object), 'hand-power-tool...', false)
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(320): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshCategoryRewrites(Object(Varien_Object), '/', false)
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(461): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshCategoryRewrites(Object(Varien_Object), NULL, false)
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(254): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshCategoryRewrite('3', '1', false)
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(248): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites('1')
#14 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites()
#15 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll()
#16 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#17 /var/www/html/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#18 /var/www/html/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#19 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0-hand-power-tools' for key 'UNQ_CATALOG_CATEGORY_ENTITY_URL_KEY_STORE_ID_VALUE'' in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Url.php(392): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('catalog_categor...', Array)
#7 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(301): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url->saveCategoryAttribute(Object(Varien_Object), 'url_key')
#8 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(320): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshCategoryRewrites(Object(Varien_Object), 'hand-power-tool...', false)
#9 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(320): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshCategoryRewrites(Object(Varien_Object), '/', false)
#10 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(461): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->_refreshCategoryRewrites(Object(Varien_Object), NULL, false)
#11 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(254): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshCategoryRewrite('3', '1', false)
#12 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php(248): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites('1')
#13 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php(257): Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->refreshRewrites()
#14 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url->reindexAll()
#15 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#16 /var/www/html/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#17 /var/www/html/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#18 {main}
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the just the affected row in core_url_rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a dump from you database:
Step 1: On you ssh shell do this command:

```
mysqldump -h databasehost -u user -pPASSWORD databasename > filename.sql
```

Step 2: So you can try:

```
TRUNCATE core_url_rewrite;
```

And try reindex again.

This should do the trick.

Comment: This is basically telling people to delete all the rewrites of a Magento installation. Do you have anything to back up your answer? Are you sure that the rewrites will be automatically regenerated after?

Comment: Yes im sure, already do that thousants of time. Sometimes we have old registrys on this table, the reindex process may broke. To guarantee we aways make a backup from database. I don't have sure this will solve the problem, but aways i have problem with rewrite truncate this table is aways a good solution. reindex process make all up right again.

Comment: This did not help. For some reason I cannot call TRUNCATE core_url_rewrite; My query is interrupted. Thanks though.

Comment: I know u can be a little unconfortable truncating this table, but fore sure it will help you. Have absoluty no reason to don't work this command. Check it out. Or die trying ;)

Comment: This is awful. Please understand the implications of this before you truncate such an important table. That person who handles all your SEO might come knocking when valuable urls no longer work because all the custom url rewrites that may have been added in the admin suddenly vanish.

Comment: Listen to @pspahn  please !

Comment: When you guys get a core_url_rewrite with more than 300k rows we talk.

Comment: maybe that is why we are talking ... you can truncate the table but it not like truncate any other index table: a @pspahn said there are some big seo implication here and your answer is not giving any hint about that ...

Comment: LOL, but it the right answer. Magento 1.7 have a bug on core_url_rewrite. If you doesn't fix it before start run your store, it will go to 300k registry on core_url_rewrite easly. At this point, you can't save the SEO work, just fix the bug truncate the table and start again. Or have nice SEO on you url's but your store is too heavy to load. Do as you wish.

Comment: @Guerra the OP is not using Magento1.7. He has tagged it as v1.9

Comment: @Guerra I have nearly 500k entries in core_url_rewrite (Mage1.9.2) and it reindexes fine.

Comment: @Guerra : URL Rewrite Management not working after Re-indexed For Category Redirect https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/210130/57334

Answer (score 8):

**Do not truncate**:
core_url_rewrite

This is the **worst** advice ever, you will lose all customized SEO urls! Just dont do it!

What worked for me was SSH and running:

```
php -f ./shell/indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_url
```

If **nothing** else works then maybe attempt the table dropping idea, but only as a last resort!

Comment: Then what is the another solution

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain why your truncate is getting interrupted, that's problematic.  You can try rebuilding the index from the shell script from the main Magento directory:

php -f ./shell/indexer.php -- -reindex catalog_url

Comment: I have tried that. I get the same error.